# Storing different properties in different tables or storing all properties in one table?

Tags: best-practices

I have multiple properties that are joined with the `items` table

all of them can be stored as a string, should I have multiple tables for different properties like:

`colors table`, `images table`, etc.

or should I make them in one table

`colors and images table`

and store all of the data in this table

I want to make a good database design, I tried to store all the data in one table but when I search these tables I get mixed data, that need to be filtered.

Is making different tables a good practice?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, separate tables for each object type is a sensible design that will serve you well later on.

You haven't provided a ton of details about these other objects `Colors` and `Images` but they are technically different objects and probably should be in separate tables then. E.g. `ItemColors` and `ItemImages`, if they're only specific to `Items`.

The only exception I'd say to the above is if **all** of the following is true:

1. They are single property objects (e.g. properties themselves) with no chance of additional properties about them being added later on.
2. They only relate specifically to `Items`.
3. They always have a 1-to-1 relationship with the `Items` (meaning one `Item` can only have one `Color` and one `Image`).

Then for *simple designs for simple applications*, they theoretically can live as columns directly in the `Items` table itself.